# taking items from map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am tring to use a map to get words from a string and map them to a widget.
I have tried this but my problem is the key for the words doe and sister get the same keys so i end up getting only one of them

String theText = "my name is doe from `http.doe.com`, my sister is selly. doe and saqil are not sister friends of koiter.";

```
  wordsMap = Map.fromIterable(text.split(' '),
         key: (v) => v,
         value: (v) => TextSpan(text: v));
```

so I tried the code below

```
  Map mapMyWord = {};
 // var wordsMap;
  var splitForSize = text.split(' ').toList();
  for(var t = 0;t<= splitForSize.length-1;t++){  
    mapMyWord[t] = {'$t':TextSpan(text: splitForSize[t])};
  }
```

but In the second code when I tried to access `mapMyWord.values.toList()` it returns a list of map data again

````` [{0: TextSpan("my")}, {1: TextSpan("name")}, {2: TextSpan("is")}, {3: TextSpan("doe")}, {4: TextSpan("````http.codeish.com````,")}, ... ,{19: TextSpan("koiter")}] `````

so my main problem is how to get the values from here.

Answer (score 1):

It returns maps because you're assigning maps with this line :

```
mapMyWord[t] = {'$t':TextSpan(text: splitForSize[t])};
```

So in the end you have a `Map<Int, Map<String, TextSpan>>`.

If you meant to turn the words of that sentence into a list of TextSpan, this would be the way :

```
var textSpanList = text.split(" ").map((word) => TextSpan(text: word)).toList();
```

If you want to do it directly in the widget tree, this would do it :

```
children: <Widget>[
            for(var word in text.split(" "))
              Text(word),
]
```

*N.B: This last snippet requires a minimum SDK of 2.2.2 in the pubspec.yaml*

Answer (score 1):

In your second code, change the assignment part:

```dart
    Map mapMyWord = {};
    // var wordsMap;
    var splitForSize = text.split(' ').toList();
    for(var t = 0;t<= splitForSize.length-1;t++){  
        mapMyWord[t] = TextSpan(text: splitForSize[t]);
    }
```

Then, `mapMyWord.values.toList()` will only return a list of `TextSpan`'s. And if you want to get some specific value from the map:

```dart
    int index = 1; //some number
    print(mapMyWord[index]); //this will return one TextSpan
```